# What is SPFILEXE.ORA?

Tags: oracle10g

what is the purpose of SPFILEXE.ORA? I often come across it when surfing the web.

BTW: It is encrypted as binary in 10g XE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an spfile is a binary format pfile basically (it's a bit more complex than that).  It's usually created using alter system commands.  One name "spfilexe.ora" is probably for a DB with the SID of XE (a default if you're using oracle 10 xe out of the box and ask it to create an instance for you if i recall).

For more on pfile vs spfile:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/pfile_spfile.htm